# Interactive push transitions like TikTok

Tags: swift, user-interface, uikit

Implements an interactive push transition, such as when transitioning from the TikTok home screen to the author's profile screen

When running in the current code, the tabbar movement is different from the transition movement

ViewController is the transition source screen and NextViewController is the transition destination screen.

Attach panGesture with InteractiveNavigationController and execute push transition step by step according to the finger

How can I fix this transition to fromViewController like tabbar is in normal push transition?

https://github.com/son/InteractiveNavigationController

[image]
[image]

ViewController & NextViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, InteractiveNavigation {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    var presentAnimation: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return nil
    }

    var dismissAnimation: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return nil
    }

    func showNext() {
        let viewController = NextViewController()
        viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
}


class NextViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
    }
}
```

Animation & NavigationController

```
import UIKit

protocol InteractiveNavigation {
    var presentAnimation: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? { get }
    var dismissAnimation: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? { get }
    func showNext()
}

enum SwipeDirection: CGFloat, CustomStringConvertible {
    case left  = -1.0
    case none  = 0.0
    case right = 1.0

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .left: return "Left"
        case .none: return "None"
        case .right: return "Right"
        }
    }
}

class InteractiveNavigationController: UINavigationController , UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    // MARK: - Properties
    var interactionController: UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition?

    // MARK: - View Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        transitioningDelegate = self
        delegate = self
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(InteractiveNavigationController.handlePan(_:))))
    }


    // MARK: - Gesture Handlers
    @objc func handlePan(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let gestureView = gesture.view else { return }

        let flickThreshold: CGFloat = 700.0
        let distanceThreshold: CGFloat = 0.3

        let velocity = gesture.velocity(in: gestureView)
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: gestureView)
        let percent = abs(translation.x / gestureView.bounds.size.width);

        var swipeDirection: SwipeDirection = (velocity.x > 0) ? .right : .left

        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            interactionController = UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition()

            if swipeDirection == .left {
                let currentViewController = viewControllers.last as? InteractiveNavigation
                currentViewController?.showNext()
            }

        case .changed:
            interactionController?.update(percent)

        case .cancelled:
            interactionController?.cancel()

        case .ended:
            if let interactionController = self.interactionController {
                if abs(percent) > distanceThreshold || abs(velocity.x) > flickThreshold {
                    interactionController.finish()
                } else {
                    interactionController.cancel()
                }

                self.interactionController = nil
                swipeDirection = .none
            }

        default:
            break
        }
    }

    // MARK: - UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        guard let _ = presenting as? InteractiveNavigation else { return nil }
        if let currentViewController = viewControllers.last as? InteractiveNavigation {
            return currentViewController.presentAnimation
        }
        return nil
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        guard viewControllers.count != 1 else { return nil }
        if let currentViewController = viewControllers.last as? InteractiveNavigation {
            return currentViewController.dismissAnimation
        }
        return nil
    }

    func interactionControllerForPresentation(using animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        return interactionController
    }

    func interactionControllerForDismissal(using animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        return interactionController
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        switch operation {
        case .push: return PushAnimatedTransitioning()
        case .pop: 
            guard let currentViewController = viewControllers.last as? InteractiveNavigation else { return nil }
            return currentViewController.dismissAnimation
        case .none: return nil
        default: return nil
        }
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, interactionControllerFor animationController: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        return interactionController
    }
}

class PushAnimatedTransitioning : NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.3
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)!
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)!
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        let duration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)
        toViewController.view.frame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toViewController)
        toViewController.view.center.x += containerView.bounds.width
        containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
            fromViewController.view.center.x -= containerView.bounds.width / 2
            toViewController.view.center.x -= containerView.bounds.width
        }) { completed in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats your question/problem?

Comment: Scriptable
Sorry, I forgot add picture, so I added.